# How to get the number of child nodes in a tree in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I aim to list the name and number of children of each member of a family using MS SQL :

Example family tree in the picture (id based)

![enter image description here][1]

The Tables I have are:

1. Family

   ```
   +------+-----------------+
    | f_id | f_name          |
    +------+-----------------+
    | 1    | Name Surname 1  |
    +------+-----------------+
    | 2    | Name Surname 2  |
    +------+-----------------+
    | 3    | Name Surname 3  |
    +------+-----------------+
    | 4    | Name Surname 4  |
    +------+-----------------+
    | 5    | Name Surname 5  |
    +------+-----------------+
    | 6    | Name Surname 6  |
    +------+-----------------+
    | 7    | Name Surname 7  |
    +------+-----------------+
    | 8    | Name Surname 8  |
    +------+-----------------+
    | 9    | Name Surname 9  |
    +------+-----------------+
    | 10   | Name Surname 10 |
    +------+-----------------+
   ```
2. Relations

```
    +----------+---------+
    | r_parent | r_child |
    +----------+---------+
    | 1        | 2       |
    +----------+---------+
    | 1        | 3       |
    +----------+---------+
    | 2        | 4       |
    +----------+---------+
    | 2        | 5       |
    +----------+---------+
    | 3        | 6       |
    +----------+---------+
    | 3        | 7       |
    +----------+---------+
    | 3        | 8       |
    +----------+---------+
    | 7        | 9       |
    +----------+---------+
    | 8        | 10      |
    +----------+---------+
```

Needed results are
**UPDATED**

```
+----------------+--------------------+
| f_name         | number of children |
+----------------+--------------------+
| Name Surname 1 | 2                  |
+----------------+--------------------+
| Name Surname 2 | 2                  |
+----------------+--------------------+
| Name Surname 3 | 3                  |
+----------------+--------------------+
| Name Surname 7 | 1                  |
+----------------+--------------------+
| Name Surname 8 | 1                  |
+----------------+--------------------+
```

Thanks for help
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SwJB9.png

Comment: And how are the results calculated?  It is not obvious for surnames 3, 7, and 8.

Comment: The relations table shows that parents has children and the picture of the family tree shows each father has how many children

Comment: How is the number calculated?  Your results do not match the data you have provided.

Comment: The needed results are corrected, it was based on some example with me, sorry. now is correct

Comment: question is updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And another one avoiding count(*)

```
SELECT
    F.f_name,
    COUNT(1) [number of children]
FROM
    Family F
    JOIN Relations R ON R.r_parent = F.f_id
GROUP BY
    F.f_name
```

additionally one with using subquery

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            F.f_name,
            (SELECT Count(1) FROM Relations R WHERE R.r_parent = F.f_id) [number of children]
        FROM
            Family F
    ) Fathers
WHERE
    Fathers.[number of children] > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like basic `join` and aggregation:

```
select f.f_name, count(*)
from family f join
     relations r
     on f.f_id = r.parent
group by f.f_name, f.f_id;
```

I thought you wanted to count the children through generations.  That requires a recursive CTE:

```
with cte as (
      select r.parent, r.r_id
      from relations r
      union all
      select cte.parent, r.r_id
      from cte join
           relations r
           on r.parent = cte.r_id
    )
select parent, count(*) as num_children
from cte
group by parent;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT family.f_id
    ,rel.[number of children]
FROM family
JOIN (
    SELECT r_parent
        ,count(*) AS [number of children]
    FROM relations
    GROUP BY r_parent
    ) rel ON rel.r_parent = family.f_id
```